# example booking faces intercept-url pattern="/secure"

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

I have an question relate with the example [booking-faces](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/booking-faces), with the parameter in spring 
`security intercept-url pattern="/secure"` what's is mapping?, where is `/secure` configured.
thnks.

Comment: Do you want i will clarify my answer better?

Answer (score 0):

SpringSecurity helps so solve security problems for Java EE applications as stated [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#introduction).
The configuration below mean that user that access in your application any URL started with `secure` should have the `ROLE_SUPERVISOR` permission

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>
```

According to the configuration you may use the following users to login (they have `ROLE_SUPERVISOR` permission)

```
keith/melbourne
erwin/leuven
```

**Added**

SpringSecurity is configured in Web.xml by filter and it inercepts all URLs :

```
<filter-mapping> 
     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

All SpringSecurity are configured in the SpringSecurity configuration file like [this](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples/blob/master/booking-faces/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml)

You can find in the file the pattern to `/secure`: `<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure" ...`

Comment: Thnks for answer, I know this is, but if you view the web.xml the pages are mapping by /spring/ <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>, and in the file security-config.xml you view that the webflow are mapping with that too default-target-url="/spring/main", Where is "/secure" mapping or config?, thnks.

Comment: SpringSecurity is configured in Web.xml by filter and it inercepts all URLs : `<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>`

Comment: Yes, of course that the filter intercepts all the URLs, but if you view in web.xml all pages start like this http://localhost:8080/spring-webflow-samples/spring/xxx.xhtml, and the flows are like /spring/main.xml I don't see where /secure, is configurated.

Comment: May be I miss your question, but SpringSecurity is configured as following: 1) You add springSecurityFilterChain in the web.xml 2) You configure all staff in the SpringSecurity configuration file:
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples/blob/master/booking-faces/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml
You can find in the file the pattern to `secure`: `<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure"`